# access fields using intermediate model attributes in Django

Tags: python, django

I have 3 models and one of them is an intermediate model as the following:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Question(models.Model):
    skip = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(Choice, through='QuestionChoice')

class QuestionChoice(models.Model):
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I am trying to access a particular question and then get the correct choice from the intermediate model.

```
First_question = Question.objects.filter(skip = True)
First_question.objects.filter(QuestionChoice__correct=True)
```

this is the error I get

```
Manager isn't accessible via Question instances
```

I have read that I can't use First_question to access the intermediate model but using Question would retrieve all the question choices which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `QuestionChoice`s of a `Question` object `question` with `question.questionchoice_set`, so:

```
first_question = Question.objects.get(id=2)
correct_choices = first_question.questionchoice_set.filter(correct=True)
```

If there is only one correct, you can use `.get(…)` instead:

```
first_question = Question.objects.get(id=2)
correct_choice = first_question.questionchoice_set.get(correct=True)
```

If you are looking for the `Choice` object, you can access this with:

```
first_question = Question.objects.get(id=2)
correct_choices = first_question.choices.filter(questionchoice__correct=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`.get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) returns an object instance (or raises error if not found)  and not and not a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet)

As your error clearly states you are trying to filter on object instance which is not possible, you should use [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter) instead

> filter() will always give you a QuerySet, even if only a single object
> matches the query - in this case, it will be a QuerySet containing a
> single element.
>
> If you know there is only one object that matches your query, you can
> use the get() method on a Manager which returns the object directly

---

also check out PEP 8 style guide for your code as variables should be snakecase